# Larger resolution than proposed in El Capitan

Tags: macos, resolution

Is it possible to get a larger resolution on my Macbook Pro than the one proposed in System Preferences ? I mean my screen is 1280x800 and I'd like to putt an even larger resolution so as to have a zoom out effect on the computer.

In each application (like Chrome for instance) I have to zoom out manually.

Answer (score 1):

A large screen resolution results in smaller icons and windows. Have you tried the large setting?

Comment: resolution is currently the greatest possible, 1280x800. But yes I'd like to go further, or to find a way to fake it since it's then possible to zoom out on each app